# FFMPEG Stream and record to file on event

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, alarm

I have few scripts realize streaming, record to file and combine stream+record.
But how to realize when streaming and some event occur to star record to file with prefilled buffer - like pre-alarm buffer.
Or saves segmented files and when event occur to combine t-5 and t+5?

Is that possible with FFMPEG + script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Use `ffmpeg` to generate HLS video segments. After the event (or even during), you can concatenate the sequential `.ts` files based on their file name or timestamp, into a temporary file, and then transmux them into a format like MP4.

I don't have any sample code to hand, but we do something similar internally. (The plan is to release this on GitHub at some point in the future)

Comment: did you make some example code in GitHub. I'm facing again same thing after few year.

Comment: We did publish this open source project which can do that (and has a nice web interface) https://github.com/InsanityRadio/OnlineVideoEditor. This is the script we were using at the time that worked great: https://gist.github.com/Jamie0/149719a13790e25d096bbb25136ec3db

Comment: not existing page at github ?

Comment: ah, someone had made the repo private!